# Navigation title not showing on view with tab view controller, but "back" navigation works

Tags: ios, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationitem, uitabview

I'm relatively new to iOS Objective-C development, and I've come across a problem that I can't find a solution to.

I have a `Table View Controller`, with two prototype cells on it, which populate fine. This `Table View Controller` is one of three `Tab Views`, and the `View` that sends to the `Tab Views` has a `Navigation Controller`. This means that the views within the `Tab Views` also have a `Navigation` bar. The bar works fine, in terms of the "back" button working as expected, and the bar being in position. However, (at least on the List View) the `Navigation Bar` isn't fully recognised - it's title doesn't appear, and the table cells start directly below the status bar, rather than below the navigation bar.

Here's a couple of screenshots showing the problem:
[image: what appears in Xcode (what I expect to happen)]
what appears in Xcode (what I expect to happen)
[image: what actually appears on my testing device (iPhone 4, iOS 7.0.4)]
And then on the device, this is what actually appears - the Back button in place and working fine, but no title field, and the table cells start too high.

I've tried adding `Navigation Bar`'s and `Navigation Items`, and while adding a `Navigation Item` allows me to put a title on in Xcode, it still doesn't appear on the device in testing. I also tried to add another `Navigation Controller` just before this view, but that didn't resolve the issue either, and it caused navigation problems further down in the heirachy.

Hope I've been clear enough, please say if I need to post more information - I'm relatively new to Xcode and so not sure what exactly is applicable and what isn't. Thanks!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

please try this code, it might fix your table position

```
// Since in iOS7 the nav bar is translucent by default, so the table view starts at (0,0)
// you can either disable the translucent, which i don't recommend unless you really want to
// or just add 64 pixel on the top of your table view
[self.YOURTABLEVIEW setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(64, 0, 0, 0)];
```

and for the title, please try this

```
self.tabBarController.navigationItem.title =@"YOUT TITLE NAME";
```

Hope that helps..

Comment: Thanks for your answer (and edit), @Xu! The `setContentInset` worked, but unfortunately the `navigationItem.title` part didn't - I still just get the working back button, but no title.

Comment: @edparry would you mind show me how you add the navigation controller? i was testing locally, the title worked for me.

Comment: Hi @Xu - I've [uploaded](http://i.imgur.com/5kCWXoN.png) a screengrab of my storyboard to Imgur, and annotated it to show how everything fits together. The problem I describe is with the three views linked to from the `Tab View Controller` - hope it makes sense.

Comment: Can you try this `self.tabBarController.navigationItem.title =@"fafda";` From your screen shot, seems like you have a navigation controller in tab bar controller. i tested exactly same hierarchy on my local, it worked

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your hierarchy as

```
NavigationController -> ViewController  -> TabBarController -> ViewController1
                                                            -> ViewController2
                                                            -> ViewController3
```

If you want to hide navigation item in viewcontroller1, Add the following line

```
 self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
```

If you want to show title in viewcontroller2, Add the following line in

```
self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO; //add this if you hide navItem viewcontroller1
[self.parentViewController.navigationItem setTitle:@"Title"];
```

If you want to hide backbutton and show title in viewcontroller3, Add the following line

```
 self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO;
[self.parentViewController.navigationItem setTitle:@"Contacts"];

self.parentViewController.navigationItem.hidesBackButton=YES;
```

Add this lines to viewdidAppear method instead of ViewdidLoad ,if you have problems inshowing when switching tabs.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but what I did to create this problem was that my buttons action was connecting to the actual table itself and not the table Controller. I removed the modal action and created a new action to the table controller and it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to click the Navigation Bar from your storyboard or nib.

[image]

Then add your title to the property.

[image]